# What gadgets are recommended for an icon designer?

Tags: software-recommendation, designers, hardware-recommendation

As an icon designer, I work with multiple sizes (above 16 pixel) for different platforms, so my regular work is quite complex. What gadgets recommended (like monitor, wacom, apple mouse, etc.) for reduce my effort and time?

Comment: long story short, it all comes down to how you prefer to work. One suggestion though is to use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) as an alternative to Illustrator

Comment: Thanks Saturns, I just think and mean which tool or gadgets going to  reduce designer work, easy to handling or comfortable work.

Comment: I use illustrator with multiple artboards sized for each icon size.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, let's see if I can help

I've been working as icon designer as long as I can remember, I also sell some sets out there.

**REMEMBER, TOOLS WON'T MAKE YOU A GOOD DESIGNER / ARTIST INSTANTLY**

There's no constant formula for it, all you need is understanding your goal.
I always use

- paper
- pencil
- scanner
- my Windows PC
- PSD

**Gadget**

For gadget, there's nothing fancy you need to have, you just need a computer to produce a digital vector icon. Mouse, regular mouse could do the trick, I used it everytime I design an icon. Wacom? Nah, that's too much, I mean the point of having wacom is make you could drawing with a freehand, if you wanna achieve a "Freehand" style, go for it then.

**Personal References**

I use Photoshop, because it can show you how pixel perfect it is, I'm not suggesting you to use illustrator because the output mostly just give you a blurry pixelated (half pixel) result, because illustrator allow you to move your object freely, and sometimes it's not snapping into the grid.

Try to design from the smallest size, then resize it. It's much easier than the other way around

Comment: Thanks Budi, 
I didn't mean it tools make a Good Designer, but the tools make reduce a designer effort and time :).

I hope you know the pixel view in Illustrator when we working in pixel view then output is better than Photoshop. The advantage is we can work both view in Illustrator :). And the Icon trend is going forward to SVG. I don't know Photoshop can help for that? 
And the Wacom mostly using freehand drawing but the Wacom also help to Icon designer effort, time and comfortable work "Wacom reduce the equipments like Paper, Pencil and Scanner" you can draw a sketch directly on screen.